# What does the following method call statement mean in Java?

Tags: java, string

```
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Today");
    str.append(" is ").append("a").append(" sunny ").append(" day.");
```

In the java code above, I understand that first I created an object of type StringBuilder. Then I used the object reference str to access the method append of the class StringBuilder. After this, I loose track. Is the method append used after str.append("is") inside the append method, or am I calling the same method in this class? Further, can anyone explain the flow of execution of the above statement. Which of the above append methods is executed first?

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger.  This will show you the flow of execution as well as the values at each point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.append(" is ")` returns the StringBuilder itself. You're calling a method on the object returned by the method. It's the same as doing

```
user.getAddress().getStreet().charAt(0);
```

Except in your code, each `append()` method call returns the same object, which allows chaining multiple method calls to the same StringBuilder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found your explanation very useful.

Answer (score 6):

The return value of `append` method is the `StringBuilder` object itself. So you can chain up the call and add more characters to the string. Otherwise, the code will be very hard to read, since you have to keep referring to the StringBuilder object every line.

Answer (score 3):

Consider taking a look at the [Builder Pattern](http://blog.naxos-software.com/index.php?/archives/79-Explaining-builder-pattern..html)(scroll down towards the end of the page). Basically the object always returns itself, so you can chain many commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Today");
str.append(" is ").append("a").append(" sunny ").append(" day.");
```

Here `str.append(" is ")` returns object of `StringBuilder` on which you are calling again    `append("a")` methnod.

`str.append(" is ").append("a")` return again `StringBuilder` reference and again you are calling `append(" sunny ")` method and so on.

So basically you are chaining the methods and that's it.